# iOS:how can I get the pitch/roll/yaw information of my iPad air?

Tags: ios, sensors, android-sensors, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I am a beginner for ios.
I need to know the pitch roll yaw information for my app.

how can I get the pitch/roll/yaw information of my iPad air ?
Which sensor should I use ?
Is there any demo?

Comment: Refer this : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/basic-sensors-in/9781449309480/ch04.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at [Core Motion API.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/)

Useful [Motion event](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html) handling.

Here is a fine [tutorial.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/motion-events-part-2-core-motion/)